# div onclick jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, onclick, event-handling

Will you help me with my code because i don't know whats wrong I'am doing. I have a jQuery that creating dinamically divs 6 of these divs should be clickable. All of these 6 divs must be as toggle which open the 5 next divs with css style "display:block".

here is my onclick function:

```
$("#weatherTiles").on('click', '.show', function() {
        var targetDiv = $(this).data("target");
        $('[class^="nextDayTile"]:not([id="'+targetDiv+'"])').hide('slow');
        if (!$('#'+targetDiv).is('visible')) {
            $('#'+targetDiv).show('slow');
        }
});
```

html

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h1>Weather</h1>
    </div>
    <section id="weatherTiles"></section>
    <section id="weatherTileNextDay"></section>
</div>
```

jQuery
These divs should show or hide.

```
$("#weatherTiles").append("<div id='myTile"+i+"'class='show' data-target='myTile"+i+"'>...."</div>");
```

These should be shown or hidden.

```
$("#weatherTileNextDay").append("<div class='nextDayTile"+i+" hide'>..."</div>");
```

Comment: So what's the problem here? What is not working and how should it be working?

Comment: After I am clicking on that div it's not working. It should show me hidden div which is in #weatherTileNextDay.

Comment: The elements with class "nextDayTile" don't have an ID which you are trying to access with `$('[class^="nextDayTile"]:not([id="' + targetDiv + '"])')` and `$('#' + targetDiv)` Remember: IDs have to be unique

Comment: @Matt Please create a `jsfiddle`, will definitely help you out.